# How to make async wrap-function for async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have 'func1' which wraps async 'func2' like:

```
func1 = function(arg1) {
    func2 (arg1, function(result) {
       // parse and return some parts of 'result'
    }, function(error) {
       alert (error.message);
    })
}
```

How to make 'func1' async too (for external code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function wrapper(callback) {//async callback is the standard for most libs
  func1(arg1);//call that original func1 you defined.
  callback(); //first arg is error, second is result (you don't have any result so it is empty)
}`